# Restarting a loop from the top

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
text_counter = 0
MAXTEXT_COUNTER = 10
puts "hello, this will start"
loop do
  puts "hello"
  text_counter += 1
  sleep(2)
  if text_counter >= MAXTEXT_COUNTER
    break
  end
end
sleep(7200)
print "ended test"
```

Once the `break` has happened, how can I get it to start again from the top?

I'm now thinking I could nest this loop in an `until` loop with the condition of `text_counter == 1000`. This would break, then sleep for 2 hours, then start again until it hits 1000.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to keep the `break`? If you get rid of the `if` condition (doing away with the need for the counter), your loop will run forever.

Comment: `10.times { puts "hello"; sleep 2 }`

Comment: I should amend the code, I want it to sleep(7200) then restart.

Comment: You can edit your original question if you need to.

Comment: You don't need the counter. As in Sagar Pandya's example, you can use the `#times` method. See the integer class [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html).

Comment: The "top" meaning... what? What specifically do you want the code to do? If you want to run the inner loop (`text_counter >= MAXTEXT_COUNTER`) n times then put the existing loop in an outer loop. And you can use `times` for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a loop within a loop where you repeat one N times, the other M times:

```
MAXTEXT_COUNTER = 10

puts "hello, this will start"

loop do
  MAXTEXT_COUNTER.times do
    puts "hello"
    sleep(2)
  end

  print "ended test"
  sleep(7200)
end
```

The outer loop is perpetual. The inner one runs a certain number of times and stops using the `times` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for **next**

It functions similarly to `break`, but returns control back to the top of the loop. It's great for creating flat control flow.

For example

```
0.upto(100) do |i|
  if i % 7 == 0
    puts "#{i} is a multiple of 7"
    next
  end

  puts i
end
```

Comment: `next` would be meaningless here; the loop already does what it's supposed to. There needs to be an *outer* loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`retry` keyword](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/1122838559/redo-vs-retry) which repeats the loop from top, just what you've asked.

Or you can wrap your loop into a method and continuously call that method.